# Mahapps.Flyouts - Content Binding

Tags: c#, mahapps.metro, flyout

I'm trying to dynamically bind a Flyout content to a view, like I would do to a TabControl, but when I load the view object the Flyout is empty. I tried loading the view directly below the **Controls:FlyoutsControl** and it worked, so I don't think the problem is with the view itself.

Also, I need to load this in a specific Flyout, so using the **ItemSource** property in the **Controls:FlyoutsControl** wouldn't work for me.

**MainWindow.xml**

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
    <Controls:FlyoutsControl>
        <Controls:Flyout 
            Content="{Binding FlyTest, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            IsOpen="{Binding IsOpen, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            Background="#91000000"/>
    </Controls:FlyoutsControl>
</Controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
```

**UserControl1.xml - The View to be loaded**

```
<controls:Flyout 
    x:Class="TestApp.View.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
    Position="Right"
    MinWidth="380" MaxWidth="380"
    Header="Manufacturer Data">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox
            Text="Test Data"
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

    </Grid>
</controls:Flyout>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
    private UserControl1 _flyTest;

    public UserControl1 FlyTest
    {
        get { return _flyTest; }
        set
        {
            _flyTest = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("FlyTest");
        }
    }

    private void LoadTabs()
    {
        FlyTest = new UserControl1();
        IsOpen = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out by changing the view object type from **Flyout** to **UserControl**